# What is the most appropriate clue here?

Tags: puzzle-creation

**Background.** I'm specifically interested in how to design a puzzles chain for a team (8-10 teenages). We are going to play at a Scientific Museum. The main the idea is to find a key and open a lock.

**My attemp is:**

Let’s say there are two types of cards: action (A1 -- turn and read, A2 -- solve and find extra piece, A3 -- ask Ceasar, A4 -- build a tower) and item (I1 -- microscop, I2 -- puzzle, I3 -- man's photo, I4 -- scheme of a tower). Players must correctly match the cards' pairs and perform the action with the item. For example, A1<->I1, A2<->I2, A3<->I3, and A4<->I4.

As a result of the three pairs (A1, I1), (A2, I2), and (A3, I3) the players can find:

1. an encrypted message (for example, phrase "**yljlpclyz huk ayhuztpaaly**"  in the microscop),
2. a cipher name  (for example, **Caesar** from the photo),
3. a cipher key (for example, the number **7** on the extra piece of puzzle).

Finally, the teams read the message "**receivers and transmitter**". This is a clue for a spatial communications puzzle, because we can use the Museum's equipment only in a specific place.

A single person should take the transmitter, look on the scheme (card I4) and give some instructions while other persons should take receivers and try to realize these instructions in order to build a tower (photo is below).

[image]

The scenario is not ready yet, but I think this team communication puzzle is the final puzzle. After this step a team should find the key and open the lock.

Question: How to provide the final clue for team? What is the most suitable approach here?

My idea is to use the QR codes for three pairs (A1, I1), (A2, I2), and (A3, I3). But the pair (A4, I4) is the "Eureka" moment.
The team should find the tower in the Museum. The tower is the key's location. The location of lock is known from the beginning.

If you need some additional information I can share it.

Comment: I saw something like this on a TV show on the BBC. I think it was probably "The Family Brain Games" hosted by Dara Ó Briain. The shapes they had to build was a bit simpler though. Anyway, I'm not sure what you are asking for. What do you mean by "the final clue"? What key and what is "the box"?

Comment: Is it possible to publish a scenario sketch here?

Comment: You're still not providing any context. Where did this box and key come from? What do you mean by suitable approach? What is a scenario sketch and what is that supposed to accomplish? What on earth do you want?

Comment: Are you asking for a way to extract a phrase/instruction from a puzzle involving assembling a structure of some kind? If so, perhaps you can include words or letters on the building blocks that will spell out the phrase when the assembly is done correctly?

Comment: @pilsnot3, you are read my mind;) a single person see the scheme name (tower, rokect, ladder...). In the game space we have the same objects.

Comment: We shouldn't need to read your mind. Please edit your question to make it clear what you want, what the requirements are, what you want to accomplish. Otherwise it is likely to be closed for being too vague.

Comment: @jaapscherphuis, I have added the details.

Comment: Is A4:I4 supposed to reveal the location of the tower?

Comment: @JMP, the A4:I4 should give an idea how to connect the current puzzle with next (final) location.